# How to build an Ethereum private chain using POS consensus

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, proof-of-stake, pow

I want to use POS consensus to build my own private chain, who can tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem. reconfig genesis.json file and problem solved. Default genesis.json will use POW instead. Here is the genesis file I use

```
{
    "config": {
    "chainId": 123455,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 5,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
    "alloc": {
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "111111111"},
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "222222222"},
      "0x7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82": { "balance": "333333333"}
  },
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000011",
  "difficulty": "0x20000",
  "extraData": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d820000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce": "0x0000001200000042",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

[source](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/private-network)

Answer (score -1):

In this link https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network
use `Clique` for Proof Of Authority

Comment: The Clique in the documentation uses POA, not POS

Comment: use Binance POS over geth https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/